# Is Matrix Good or Bad?

Tags: algorithm

A matrix B (consisting of integers) of dimension N × N is said to be good if there exists an array A (consisting of integers) such that B[i][j] = |A[i] - A[j]|, where |x| denotes absolute value of integer x.

You are given a partially filled matrix B of dimension N × N. Q of the entries of this matrix are filled by either 0 or 1. You have to identify whether it is possible to fill the remaining entries of matrix B (the entries can be filled by any integer, not necessarily by 0 or 1) such that the resulting fully filled matrix B is good.

> Example
>
> Input 4
>
> 2 2
>
> 1 1 0
>
> 1 2 1
>
> 2 3
>
> 1 1 0
>
> 1 2 1
>
> 2 1 0
>
> 3 2
>
> 2 2 0
>
> 2 3 1
>
> 3 3
>
> 1 2 1
>
> 2 3 1
>
> 1 3 1
>
> Output
>
> yes
>
> no
>
> yes
>
> no

Here is my code, but failing some tests.

> ## include int main(){
>
> ```
> int t;
> scanf("%d", &t);
> while(t--){
>     int n, q;
>     scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
>     int arr[n][n];
>     int brr[n];
>     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
>         brr[i]=1;
>         for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
>             arr[i][j]=-1;
>     }
>     int result=0;
>     while(q--){
>         int l, r, val;
>         scanf("%d %d %d", &l, &r, &val);
>         arr[l-1][r-1]=val;
>         arr[r-1][l-1]=val;
>         if( abs(brr[l-1]-brr[r-1])!=val  && l!=r){
>             brr[r-1]=brr[r-1]-val;
>         }
>     }
>     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
>         printf("%d ", brr[i]);
>     printf("\n");
>     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
>         for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
>             if(arr[i][j]!=-1 ){
>                 if( abs(brr[i]-brr[j])==arr[i][j] &&  abs(brr[i]-brr[j])==arr[j][i]){
>                     continue;
>                 }
>                 else{
>                     result=1;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         if(result)
>             break;
>     }
>     if(result)
>         printf("no\n");
>     else
>         printf("yes\n");
> }
> return 0; }
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is not a free pump-and-dump homework service.  If you have a specific question, having shown effort and having gotten stuck, then please ask that instead of dumping a question here.

Comment: smells like homework.

Comment: But i want to know the approach for this question i don't want the solution @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TomSchardt I want the approach for the question. I'm not asking for someone to write the code.

Comment: can anyone help me ....

Comment: @Madhu try to derive new conclusions from the given constraints using paper and pencil. So far all you can present is some barely readable code that doesn't look like you've done that. Anyways, small hint: `B[a][b] = |A[a] - A[b]| = |A[b] - A[a]| = B[b][a]` is a **constraint**, not something fixed for every input.

Answer (score 0):

The question is from live contest : https://www.codechef.com/SEPT17/problems/FILLMTR/. Please focus on learning rather than increase the count of accepted problems.